# include network interface name in report

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking

I am working on a batch script that reports latency in to a csv file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
set total=0
for /F "tokens=3,7 delims==: " %%G in ('ping google.com ^| findstr /C:"Reply from"') do (
 set /a count+=1
 SET ms=%%H
 set ms=!ms:ms=!
 set /a total=!total! + !ms!
)
set /a average=%total% / %count%
set curTime=%date:~7,2%/%date:~3,3%/%date:~10,4%-%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%
echo %curTime%, %computername%, Latency is, %average%, ms >> "\\server\Reports\%computername%.csv"
```

I want to include the network interface used for pinging. Is the PC on LAN or Wireless network? So I can include `%interface%` in report.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you take a look at the output of `set /?` at the Command Prompt, you'll note that, `set /a total=!total! + !ms!` should be `set /a total=total + ms` or `set /a total +=ms` and `set /a average=%total% / %count%` should be `set /a average=total / count`.

Comment: As for your question, it is not the role of the members of this site, to add code to what you already have in order to add functionality, that unfortunately requires that you research and write it yourself. This site helps to fix a single specific issue with your provided code, given that code and a full explanation of how it fails to work as written and intended.

Comment: BTW, the average is already calculated and written in the output from your `ping` command, so you may find it simpler using this as a basis: `For /F "Tokens=3 Delims=," %%# In ('Ping google.com^|Find "Average"')Do Echo(%%#`